# Transferring Data According to Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, vba

If it says "None" in cell DA9, can you help me to get a warning as "Record exists" if it says "Exists" for the following process.

If it says "None";
Let it copy cells DD9:DX11 on the home page (cells with formulas exist)
Let it find the empty cell after the BY3 cell of the data sheet and transfer it (without taking the formula)

Protected on two pages (password 12345)

I request your help in this matter.

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngTarget As Range
Dim iRow As Integer

Sheets("Giriş").Unprotect "12345"
Sheets("Data").Unprotect "12345"

If Sheets("Giriş").Range("DA9") = "Yok" Then
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Giriş").Range("Girişdata") 
iRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 77).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Data").Range("BY" & iRow)
rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngTarget
```

Else
Sheets("Giriş").Range("DA9") = "Var"
MsgBox ("Bu veri var")
End If

```
Sheets("Giriş").Protect Password:="12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Pieces As Integer
Sheets("Login").Select
If Range("da9").Value = "None" Then
Sheets("Input").Range("DD9:DX11").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("BY3").Select
Quantity = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Count
Range("BY" & 3 + Pieces).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
ElseIf Range("da9").Value = "There is" Then
MsgBox ("Record Exists")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).